# Rails: Displaying published post by all and unpublished post of current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I wanted to know how one would do the following:

- A user can view all published Posts
- A user can view view their unpublished Post

Code:

```
# Post model
scope :published, where(is_published: true)
scope :unpublished, where(is_published: false)

# Post controller
def index
 @Post = Post.published
 if user_signed_in?
   @Post = Post.published && Post.unpublished.where(user_id: current_user.id)
 end
end
```

I'm not really sure what the right way to setup an active record condition to display what I'm after.

Any much is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close! Just replace && with +

```
# Post controller
def index
 @posts = Post.published
 if user_signed_in?
   @posts = Post.published + Post.unpublished.where(user_id: current_user.id)
 end
end
```

Be aware that joining like this will change the @posts object from a relation to an array.

Also take a look at @SachinR's answer for a nice refinement to the `Post.unpublished.where(user_id: current_user.id)` line.

Based on your requirement I think you could do better with a scope:

```
#Post model
scope :published_and_user, lambda{|user| where("is_published = ? OR user_id = ?", true, user.id)}
scope :ordered, :order => "created_at DESC"

# Post controller
def index
 @posts = Post.published.ordered
 if user_signed_in?
   @posts = Post.published_and_user(current_user).ordered
 end
end
```

And now you have a relation that is ordered properly, and only one scope!

Comment: Hey Matt! Thanks for your response. Great tip RE relation vs array. When I was using the + and trying to display it in my view, it only displayed the published posts but I guess I have to keep figure out how this join works.

Comment: Is there a way to display both Post.published.order('created_at DESC') + Post.unpublished.order('created_at DESC') in order DESC. It seems to display the published post first then the unpublished when called in a block @post.each do |p|.

Comment: Since it becomes an array you can easily do a `sort_by`, but based on your requirement I think you could build a better solution with some scopes, I've added an example.

Comment: Matt, thanks for taking the time and helping me out. I've learned a lot from you going through all the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

To get all published records

```
   @posts = Post.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).published
```

To get all unpublished records

```
   @posts = Post.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).unpublished
```

or

```
If Post belongs to user 

    class Post
      belongs_to :user
    end

then you can directly use 
current_user.posts.published
current_user.posts.unpublished
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin, the current_user.posts.published is a big helper. In terms of combining both published and unpublished in a view block, how do you do it [@post, @unpublished_post_by_user].each do |p|

Comment: @WasabiDeveloper you can join two collections with +, demonstrated in my answer above :)

Comment: posts = @post + unpublished_post_by_user

Comment: Thanks guys! I owe you both a coffee and a hug. I appreciate both your time.